# Calculating the Mean Bias Error (MBE) of data set?

Tags: r, matrix

How to calculate the MBE of two columns of data in a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tdStats` function from the `tdr` packages. There are multiple functions you can check in this function for error statistics:

> There are also functions that normalize the MBE, MAE and RMSE values.
> nmbe, nmae, and nrmse use the observation range as factor of
> normalization, while cvmbe, cvmae, and cvrmse, use the observation
> average to normalize.

Example:

```
library(tdr)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(10, 0, 1),
                 y = runif(10, 0, 1))

tdStats(df$x, df$y, functions = "mbe")
```

Output:

```
       mbe 
-0.1953218
```

Comment: Link to tdr package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tdr/index.html